# unexpected labal '38' deepLab error

Tags: caffe, image-segmentation

I am trying to finetune deepLab network used for Semantic Segmentation on my own data which has pixel-wise labels for 2 classes: 'hands' and background. My ground truth segmentation maps are binary maps with 1 for hands and 0 for background.

I changed deeplab-largeFOV network to have 2 output labels instead of 21 (21 when trained on PASCAL VOC) and tried to run it. It somehow changes my labels from 1 to 38 and then throws following error:

```
F1101 20:47:22.904304 21648 seg_accuracy_layer.cpp:92] Unexpected label  38. num: 0. row: 3. col: 15
```

I tried printing values it takes for ground truth from "interp" layer and it seems that for some reason my labels for hands are being converted to 38. Can someone please explain me why it is happening?

I am stuck on it since more than a week and it is really frsutrating now. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: No, seg_accuracy_layer.cpp still throws same error. I changed the accuracy layer from "SegAccuracy" to "Accuracy" and then everything works fine for me.

Comment: @AUKhan you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Change the accuracy layer from "SegAccuracy" to "Accuracy" and then this error will go away.

Comment: I think it should work for more than 2 classes as well, since we are replacing the "SegAccuracy" layer with standard "Accuracy" layer, and this fix is not dependent on number of classes.